# couchdb offset: I get no results

Tags: couchdb

I make an ajax request to couchdbwith POST method, giving a list of keys of the docs I want to retrieve.

Everything seems to work fine except the fact that I get 0 rows because the offset is set on the last line.

So it means that:

1. I'm communicating well with couchdb server (cloudant)
2. the POST method works
3. it seems to retrieve the list but just giving it with the offest of last element, i.e. an empty list

Also, trying to order the results differently had no success.

`riList` var is something like this (from google chrome dev tools):

```
keys: Array[194]
0: "Wire line diamond core drilling rig"
1: "VUA - isotope geochemistry laboratory"
2: "Volcanologic and Seismological Observatories"
3: "VESOG"
4: "Utrecht University - TecLab, Tectonic Laboratory"
5: "Utrecht University - Experimental and Analytical Laboratories"
.....
```

which basically is the same of

```
var riList=["Wire line diamond core drilling rig", "VUA - isotope geochemistry laboratory","Volcanologic and Seismological Observatories","VESOG","Utrecht University - TecLab, Tectonic Laboratory","Utrecht University - Experimental and Analytical Laboratories"];
```

Here is the code

```
            var riList= ListOfRU.pluck('ri_name');
            var queryParams={"keys":riList};
            var riResponseList=[];
            var ajaxURL= ('_view/'+ self.parentMcDropDownValue);
            console.log(ajaxURL, queryParams);
            $.ajax({ //retrieve and show on map LABORATORY coordinates
                async: true, 
                url: ajaxURL,
                type:"POST",
                data:JSON.stringify(queryParams),
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout:5000,
                success:function(response){
                    console.log("response",response);
                    riResponseList=response.rows;
                    },
                error:function(){
                    alert('fetching error');
                    }
                });
```

chrome developer tools output

```
response 
Object
offset: 194
rows: Array[0]
total_rows: 194
__proto__: Object
```

as you can see in the output of chrome devtools the offset is 194 so that I have an array with 0 rows because it starts from the last key.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was tempted to delete this question when I found the bug.

But finally I decided to let it and to explain what was wrong.

If you feel it should be deleted, please motivate this and I'll delete it.

So the answer to my question is very simple: the keys I was retrieving WERE NOT the keys I was selecting with the `"keys"` parameter.

The error was indeed in the `map` function where I wrote:

```
//WRONG ONE!!
function(doc){
    if(doc.doctype=='ri'){
        emit(doc.ri, doc);
    }
}
```

**INSTEAD OF**

```
//RIGHT ONE!!
function(doc){
    if(doc.doctype=='ri'){
        emit(doc.ri_name, doc);// RI_NAME INSTEAD OF RI!!!!!
    }
}
```

So the lesson is:

*When you get an offset which equals the lenght of the array,  check if the results are really the one you want to obtain with the map function.*

Comment: Thanks for not deleting this. I have an offset in my results now and I'm trying to figure out why... What exactly does the offset parameter say?